# css selector for instagram post alongside comments not working

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

In my example code below I have navigated to Obama's first Instagram post. I am trying to point to the portion of the page that is his post and the comments beside it.

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B-Sj7CggmHt/")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div._97aPb")
```

I want this to work for the page of any post and of any Instagram user, but it seems that the xpath for the post alongside the comments changes. How can I find the post image + comments combined block regardless of which post it is? Would appreciate any help thank you.

I would also like to be able to individually point to the image and individually point to the comments. I have gone through multiple user profiles and multiple posts but both the xpaths and css selectors seem to change. Would also appreciate guidance on any reading or resources where I can learn how to properly point to different html elements.

Comment: I believe the selector `div._97aPb` is going to be different every time you load the page, it is auto generated specifically to make scraping in this way harder

Comment: Any tips on finding a way to point to it given that it is different every time?

Answer (score 1):

You could try selecting based on the top level structure. Looking more closely, there is always an `article` tag, and then the photo is in the 4th div in, right under the header.

[image]

You can do this with `BeautifulSoup` with something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup 
article = soup.find('article')
divs_in_article = article.find_all('div')
```

`divs_in_article[3]` should have the data you are looking for. If `BeautifulSoup` grabs dives under that first `header` tag, you may have to get creative and skip that tag first. I would test it myself but I don't have ChromeDriver running right now.

Alternatively, you could try:

```
images = soup.find_all('img')
```

to grab all image tags in the page. This may work too.

BeautifulSoup has a lot of handy methods to get you tagging things based on structure. Take a look at [going back and forth](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-back-and-forth), [going sideways](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) , [going down](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down) and [going up](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up). You should be able to discern the structure using the developer tools in your browser and then come up with a way to select the collections you care about for comments.